# Can I use "Currently" for a span of time?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Can I write "Currently, I am a university instructor for more than 3 years"

I mean is it a correct usage of "Currently" and "more than 3 years"?

Comment: I am currently a university instructor for over three years. That's how I'd put it. :)

Comment: @Joe: "currently" is a synonym for "now".  Do you think the sentence works with "now"? "am... for over"?

Comment: @TRomano why are you sending nonsense comments to me?

Answer (score 3):

When talking about a span of time, I would switch the *am* to *have been*:

> Currently, I have been a university instructor for more than 3 years.

Some might say that the "currently" sounds a little awkward with "I have been", and I wouldn't disagree. So this might be better written as:

> I am currently a university instructor, and have been for more than 3 years.

This wording indicates the work is currently ongoing, and also specifies how long it has been going on for, without a jarring verb tense.